# Schedule jobs for quartz scheduler from other spring boot application

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler

I have two spring boot applications, where one features the creating and scheduling of the job.  There is another Spring Boot application where I configured the Quartz Scheduler, which will prepare the job parameters using a shared database and launches the spring batch job.

I need to update the running Quartz Scheduler if the user updates or adds a new job from UI. Also if server restarts I need to restart the Scheduler and the Jobs.

How should I update my Quartz Scheduler object when there's the new job added or updated by the user? My Quartz Scheduler will always be in running condition. Can I use REST Template so that my UI application will notify my scheduler application for the jobs?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the jobs to schedule in a database (using the share database) from the UI application, create a job and build a trigger for it.

Its hard to say without any code given, but there is a guide that does something like you want.

https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-email-scheduling-example/

This is a dynamic scheduler/trigger

Comment: yes I am able to use the saved triggers from database